# BEST method for redirecting from Desktop or Mobile?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, mobile-development

Is there a consensus on the best method of redirecting from Desktop to Mobile ?  I am working with a very good developer but he has little experience with anything other than responsive sites.

(I know its better to have a responsive site, but recently spent 30% of my year's business income trying and failing to get a good quality redesign to a responsive version of our existing site)

So I have a 55 page Desktop Site and a new 55 page Mobile site.  The mobile site works OK on all mobile platforms we have tested.

For example is using mobile-detect.php a good solution, or what else should we consider ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for redirecting:

```
<script>
window.location.href = "www.TheSite.com";
</script>
```